# Vectorize a for loop in which the input depends on the output

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have a complicated problem about vectorization of a dependence for loop, I would like to have some helps from you.

Let's `X1` be a vector with length `n1`, `X2` be a vector with length `n2`, `F1` be a `N1`x`n1` matrix, `F2` be a `N2`x`n2` matrix, `Q` be a `N1`x`N2` matrix, and the notation `p...` are index vectors. ntrapz is a function for trapezoidal numerical integration. I would like to compute the matrix `Q` as follows:

```
for i1=1:N1
    F1_13tmp=F1(i1, p1_13)';                       % ' 
    F1_13=F1_13tmp(:,ones(n2,1));
    for i2=1:N2
        F2_13 = F2(i2, p2_13);
        Q_13_13 = Q(p1_13, p2_13);
        Q(i1,i2) = Q(i1,i2) + 
              ntrapz(X2(p2_13), ntrapz(X1(p1_13)', Q_13_13.*F1_13).*F2_13);
    end
end
```

The problem is that updating `Q(i1,i2)` changes the value of `Q_13_13 = Q(p1_13, p2_13)` for the next iteration. I would like to know if we can vectorize a such for loop. If not, any idea to speed up the code?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The old advice to vectorise everything in Matlab is just that, old advice.  Recent (since 2010 perhaps) advances in the Matlab run time make loop-based programs as fast as vectorised in many cases.  I won't state either that you can't vectorise your code (because of loop dependencies) or that you won't see a performance improvement if you do, but don't raise your expectations that a vectorised version will show a significant performance improvement, one large enough to justify the time you (and SO in general) spent on devising it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have Matlab R2010b, and I do not know if loop-based programs is really as fast as vectorized ones. In the program since N1*N2 is relatively big (91204), so even if a simple command as "Q_13_13 = Q(p1_13, p2_13)" take a considerable time (1,06s).

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization is typically the way to go for parallel operations. However, in your case it appears that you have sequential operations and those are generally not suitable for vectorization.

I am not familiar with the function you use, but the only way I can think of to possibly speed up your calculation is writing it in a non-dependand form. Note that this is more of a math exercise than a programming exercise, here is a simple example:

Suppose the formula is equal to:

```
Y(1)=0.5;
Y(t)=0.3*Y(t-1)+epsilon(t);
% Let as assume epsilon is also known
epsilon = rand(9,1)
```

The simple way to calculate Y(10) would be to do 10 calculation steps.

```
for t=2:10
    Y(t)=0.3*Y(t-1)+epsilon(t);
end
```

The fastest way to calculate Y(10) would be to do something like this (not sure if it is correct, but should be close)

```
Y(10)=Y(1)*0.3^9 + sum(epsilon.^(1:9))
```

So to conclude: The only way to "vectorize" the loop, is if you can help the computer significantly and basically let it do a different calculation. If this is not possible you can of course always try to squeeze out a bit of extra speed by making it a mex file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. If I'm not wrong, your example returns the last element of the for-loop. This seems not be applicable to my case, because I need all positions of matrix Q. In the program, the matrix Q is updated with each iteration in the way that each position of matrix Q is the results of the integral of the last updated Q. Maybe the vectorization is impossible ?!